# bat закрывается доходя до команды if

Tags: bat, if

Кодом проверяю запуск приложений. Вот часть кода с которой начинает вылетать, после нее идет похожий код на другие два приложения

```
set imagename=TaskbarX.exe
tasklist /fi "IMAGENAME eq %imagename%" | find /i "%imagename%"
if errorlevel 1 (
cd C:\Program Files (x86)\TaskbarX
start TaskbarX.exe
goto :b
) else (
goto :b
)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Эта команда

```
cd C:\Program Files (x86)\TaskbarX
```

считывается как несколько из-за пробелов в пути.
Попробуйте писать так:

```
cd "C:\Program Files (x86)\TaskbarX"
```

https://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch001267.htm